# How to move/switch one database to another database using shell script(psql)?

Tags: postgresql, psql

How can I move or switch one database to another database using PostgreSQL 9.3 version in shell script(psql)?

**Example**:

```
 testdb=#
```

**to**

```
 mydb=#
```

Comment: check out the `\connect` command in the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean in a script sourced by `psql` via `-f` or `\i`, you can use the command `\connect` (shorthand `\c`).

It doesn't just switch databases, it actually disconnects and reconnects. Any `SET` commands, etc, are not preserved across reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below statement:

`\c database name`